# How to capture value from rs.next() before looping through sql database?

Tags: java, sql, resultset

[SQL db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VS10v.png)

Refer the image.

I am new to Java.So in the table I want var x to point to first row.Initially var y should also point to first row.I want to just update y variable to next row in the while loop every time keeping x static until x and y matches.In the else part once value of y changes I need to update x to new value which matches y.How to do so?

```
var x= Initial;//dont know how to capture value over here.
while(rs.next){
var y=rs.getInt(1);
if(y==x){
 }
else{}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
    int x= 0;
    while(rs.next){
        if (x == 0){
            x=rs.getInt(1);
        }
        int  y = rs.getInt(1);
        if(y !=x){
            x=y;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is fine upto 3 rows .How to then update x to row 4 value?

Comment: That is handled in the if clause . If x != y then x will updated to y

Answer (score 0):

you can get the values from a resultSet as below:

```
while(result.next()) {

    result.getString("columnName");
    result.getInt("columnName");
}
```

Or

```
while (resultSet.next()) {
            ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
            int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
                resultSet.getObject(i);
            }
        }
```